# How do you change the camera default on a sony z3

Tags: android

Is it possible to change the default action of the camera button on a Sony Z3?

Answer (score 0):

You can check for yourself. Install [Internal Broadcast Monitor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lt.andro.broadcastlogger)  from Google Play. Start the log, go to the camera app, and then press the hardware button. This will tell you what intent is being broadcasted by that button.

Then, you'll have to write a [broadcast receiver](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html) yourself with the same intent-filter, assign a high priority to it, and abort the broadcast once intercepted.

This may, or may not, work. It will depend entirely on the priority originally given the sony developers to their own broadcast receiver. If theirs is too high already, you won't be able to intercept the broacast. If it's low enough, it will work. Hopefully, it will be low enough.